java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method rememberComposableLambda
While launch scan with this plugin  '@capacitor/barcode-scanner'
but i have this Exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method rememberComposableLambda(IZLjava/lang/Object;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;I)Landroidx/compose/runtime/internal/ComposableLambda; in class Landroidx/compose/runtime/internal/ComposableLambdaKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaKt' appears in /data/app/~~mK_bGGqANgiVGzIdyQh2Yw==/com.mycompany.caisse.debug-ILKcoyuBxwK5azm899YlKw==/base.apk) 
at com.outsystems.plugins.barcode.view.OSBARCScannerActivity$onCreate$3.invoke(OSBARCScannerActivity.kt:204)
at com.outsystems.plugins.barcode.view.OSBARCScannerActivity$onCreate$3.invoke(OSBARCScannerActivity.kt:198)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:428)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:194)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)" 

my config is there:
1- build.graddle(android):
"// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
    url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OutSystemsRD/9e79bc5b-69b2-4476-9ca5-d67594972a52/_packaging/PublicArtifactRepository/maven/v1'
    name 'Azure'
    credentials {
        username = "optional"
        password = ""
    }
    content {
        includeGroup "com.github.outsystems"
    }
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
} 
" 

2- build.graddle(app):
" 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    namespace "com.mycompany.caisse"
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.caisse.debug"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 14
        versionName "3.3.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
            // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
            // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
} 
"

3- graddle info :
"
Gradle 8.2.1

Build time:   2023-07-10 12:12:35 UTC
Revision:     a38ec64d3c4612da9083cc506a1ccb212afeecaa

Kotlin:       1.8.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.12 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64
"

While launch scan with this plugin  '@capacitor/barcode-scanner'
Need help to resolve this Exception

Same case. It just stopped working.
UPDATE
The problem was solved by uninstalling the plugin and installing version 1.0.2.

Thank you very much, it works! I uninstalled the package with npm uninstall @capacitor/barcode-scanner; npx cap sync and installed this version with npm install @capacitor/barcode-scanner@1.0.2; npx cap sync
